# Comparison of means in R

Tags: r, mean

I have the following boxplots of a quantitative trai by medication group. I would like to compare Med0 against all the other groups. Which statistical test in R would be appropriate in this case?Med0 are basically healthy individuals and med1-4 cases in different medications. All groups contain independent samples.

Thanks[image]

Comment: I'd say an Anova is what you're looking for. Normally, the first group (Med0) will be estimated as intercept and the other groups will be estimated as deviation from the intercept. An Anova would also naturally extend to comparisons across Med1 - Med4. However, if you don't want to do those you don't have to. First do an Anova, if it is significant then do post hoc comparisons between Med0 and Med1-Med5.

Comment: Flagged as off topic. I think this is better suited for stats.stackexchange. This is a question about which hypothesis test to use rather than a programming problem in R.

Comment: It is off topic, so just a quick tip: you may go straight to the https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/TukeyHSD.html to actually have some meaningful results.

Comment: @m-dz Although that would work, it looks like it might be less powerful than some other relatively simple procedures. HSD compares *all* means.  The question here is more limited; that of comparing four specified means to one control mean.

Comment: @whuber, out of curiosity (and probably a lack of knowledge...), might you shortly explain why it might be less powerful than e.g. ANOVA (if that is what you mean by an other procedure)? The results (like the coefficients) seem to be exact for both (by e.g. using `aov()` or `anova(lm())` and `TuckeyHSD()` functions in **R**), of course for Med0-Med1, Med0-Med2 etc. pairwise comparison. **Edit**: Looking at it now, this might actually be a separate question...

Comment: @m-dz Because the Tukey HSD is testing *all* differences in means simultaneously, and this question asks only to test *certain* differences in means, there must be a better solution than the HSD.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for the answer. It is still not clear to me why one might be "less powerful" then the other, especially that we are no longer using pen and paper to do the calculations, but I will investigate it further on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend using a [T-Test for comparison of means](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm) for each individual comparison against the Med0 group:

$$ T_k = \frac{\bar{X}_2 - \bar{X}_1}{\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}}}$$

Where

$$\qquad k = \min( n_1 - 1, n_2 - 1)$$

$$\qquad s^2 = \frac{\sum (X_{i} - \bar{X})^2}{n-1}$$

This can be done in R with the following command:

```
t.test(Med0,Med1)
```

Comment: This is incorrect because it ignores the strong dependencies among the four tests induced by the common control group in each.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @whuber. Could you please explain further why this method is incorrect, or perhaps cite an academic paper for an explanation? I'm curious as to what context the results of doing individual t-tests would be invalid? (Especially since all groups are assumed independent)

Comment: I believe just about any account of ANOVA will include an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Variances do not look equal, this can violate the t-test assumptions. See below from SPSS documentation:

> Assumption #6: There needs to be homogeneity of variances. You can
>   test this assumption in SPSS Statistics using Levene’s test for
>   homogeneity of variances. In our enhanced independent t-test guide, we
>   (a) show you how to perform Levene’s test for homogeneity of variances
>   in SPSS Statistics, (b) explain some of the things you will need to
>   consider when interpreting your data, and (c) present possible ways to
>   continue with your analysis if your data fails to meet this assumption
>   https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/independent-t-test-using-spss-statistics.php

In R you can test homogeneity of variances via

```
library(car)
leveneTest
```

I recommend you use `pairwise.wilcox.test` for nonparametic approach of testing equality of central values for multiple groups.

Comment: That's an interesting observation.  One might consider any treatment group with variance significantly different from the variance of the control group to be *prima facie* evidence of a difference between the groups.  This points out the sense in which the question does not specify what *kind* of comparison is needed.  But doesn't the pairwise Wilcoxon test in `R` test *all* possible differences?  That would be too conservative.

Comment: ANOVA and t-tests assume equal variances; they just test if the central values differ. Welch's t-test allows to unequal variances (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test). ANOVA's F-test can handle unequal variances only if the samples are approximately equal. A pairwise Wilcoxon may be a bit conservative, but it's my personal preference as I would probably want to understand the differences between all groups.